# nginx php can't write files on CentOS machine

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, php

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "w")
?>
```

And the following permissions in my `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory

```
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root  4096 Nov 20 08:51 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root    17 Nov 18 23:48 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   537 Sep 16 14:56 50x.html
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  1171 Nov 20 03:50 make.php
```

But when I run the above PHP code which is in the `make.php` it doesn't create the `testfile.txt`!

What is wrong here? I also tried changing the user to `nginx` with the `chown` command but it doesn't work.

Comment: Short answer: SELinux.

Comment: Do I need to install this?

Comment: Oh wait i found something how to disable it: http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically I had to change to this:

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

in the `/etc/selinux/config` file. More info here: [How to Disable SELinux](https://www.crypt.gen.nz/papers/how-to-disable-selinux/).

I don't know if this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hahah! First of all .. I love your username, "ctrlz".

Regarding your issue and SELinux:

The web is scattered with posts of people recommending to disabling SELinux. It is definitely the simplest "solution", but it is not ideal in a production environment as it leaves your server more vulnerable.

Yesterday, I took a second dive into learning SELinux. I found the talk, [SELinux for Mere Mortals](https://youtu.be/bQqX3RWn0Yw) (40min), by [Thomas Cameron](https://twitter.com/thomasdcameron) very helpful.

I don't know what Linux distribution you are using (and I'm not sure how much, if at all, SELinux varies between the others), but CentOS provides a [SELinux Guide](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux).

---

### Quick Intro:

SELinux "contexts" are shown in the format `user:role:type:range`. By default, SELinux ships in the `targeted` mode, which limits access to resources by the `type` attribute.

You can append the `-Z` flag to commands such as `ps`, `ls`, `cp`, `mv`, `mkdir`, `netstat`, and more to view SELinux contexts on different resources.

To view the SELinux contexts of your web folder, run:

```
ls -lZ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

To view the context of your `nginx` process, run:

```
ps -auxZ | grep -i nginx
```

There are also SELinux "booleans" that can be enabled / disabled for common use cases. To view a list of booleans related to a web server (`nginx` in this case), run:

```
getsebool -a | grep -i httpd
```

To update a boolean value, you can set it using the `setsebool` command. Example:

```
setsebool httpd_read_user_content 1
```

A few other helpful commands:

- SELinux Labeling

  - [chcon](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-0f6390ddacfab39ee973ed8018a32212c2a02199) - temporarily change context of a file
  - [semanage fcontext](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-0f6390ddacfab39ee973ed8018a32212c2a02199) - permanently change context of a file
  - [restorecon](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-65817443e1aad7a1d1c87f6a4dc73a964b38224b) - restore contexts
- Helpful utilities

  - [audit2allow](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01)

---

That's about where I am at with my SELinux know-how at the moment. I know this is an old post, but I hope this will help others.